# What's the difference between assigning a variable as Object and assigning a variable as Object Literal Notation/Object Constructor Notation?

Tags: javascript

I just happened to notice that when assigning a variable as an `Object`, the typeof the variable is a 'function' whereas if I assign it as an empty object using object literal notation `{}` or instantiate as a `new Object`, the typeof variable is an object.
What's the difference here?

Please note, I'm not asking the difference between Object literal notation and constructor notation.

[image]

Comment: `new Object()` is different from `Object`. The latter is a constructor function!

Comment: `typeof` is not a function, you don’t need the parentheses. `typeof a;` is sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

The global symbol `Object` refers to the Object *constructor function*. Assigning `Object` to a variable just makes a copy of that reference, and is completely different from assigning a reference to a new empty object (`{}`).

Perhaps you're thinking of:

```
var a = new Object();
var b = {};
```

Those two statements do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

When you assign a variable as an Object it references the Object function onto it whereas when you do new Object or {} it just creates a plain object with the constructor method of it's parent Object

You can understand more with screenshots

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`a = Object;` doesn't create a new object. It assigns the constructor function to your variable `a`. To create a new object, use this code: `a = new Object();`

Answer (score 1):

`let a = new Object();`

Creates a new Object, printed as `{}`.

`let a = {};`

Creates a new Object, printed as `{}`. Not really different from the approach above.

`let a = Object;`

`Object` is the constructor, calling it will return a new object but it's better practice to use the `new` keyword for code conventions. I personally choose to use `let a = {};` in JavaScript. A constructor is a function, which is why the console told you it just created a function.